# TSQL Dynamic Query Into A View

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to create a dynamic sql query that's able to run on either database - and return it as a **view**. The query is not a problem, that problem is already solved. My problem is that I'm not sure how to actually return it as a view in the end. I've tried using it as a **Stored Procedure** and a **Table-valued Function** but there are issues with both solutions so far.

---

### Stored Procedure version:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetPickSummaryTable
AS
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @PickSummaryTable TABLE (
        COLUMN_A date,
        COLUMN_B nvarchar(16),
        COLUMN_C int
    )

    DECLARE @database nvarchar(64)
    DECLARE @log_database nvarchar(64)
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
    
    IF(LEFT(DB_NAME(), 4) = 'log_')
    BEGIN
        SET @log_database = DB_NAME()
        SET @database = SUBSTRING(DB_NAME(), 5, LEN(DB_NAME()) - 4)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @log_database = 'log_' + DB_NAME()
        SET @database = DB_NAME()
    END

    SET @sql = '
        SELECT c.COLUMN_A, C.COLUMN_B, pl.COLUMN_C
        FROM
            ' + @log_database + '..PICK_LOG pl
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ' + @database + '..[CUSTOM] c ON pl.CUSTOM_NUM = C.CUSTOM_NUM AND pl.COMPANY = c.COMPANY
        WHERE pl.[TIMESTAMP] > DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE())
    UNION
        SELECT c.COLUMN_A, C.COLUMN_B, pl.COLUMN_C
        FROM
            ' + @database + '..PICK_LOG pl
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ' + @database + '..[CUSTOM] c ON PL.CUSTOM_NUM = C.CUSTOM_NUM AND pl.COMPANY = c.COMPANY
        WHERE pl.[TIMESTAMP] > DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE())'

    INSERT INTO @PickSummaryTable ([DATE], CUSTOM_GROUP, CUSTOM_NUM, COMPANY, CUSTOM_DESC, LINES, QTY_SUF, DISTINCT_ORDERS)
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql 
    
    SELECT [DATE], CUSTOM_GROUP, CUSTOM_NUM, COMPANY, CUSTOM_DESC, LINES, QTY_SUF, DISTINCT_ORDERS
    FROM @PickSummaryTable
END
```

This correctly returns the table of data that I want to return as a view if run on either "database" or "log_database". But I can't access the result of a stored procedure in a view.

The view I want to create would look something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PICK_SUMMARY]
AS
WITH A AS (
    EXEC sp_GetPickSummaryTable
) 
SELECT * FROM A
```

---

### Table-valued Function version:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_GetPickSummaryTable()
RETURNS @PickSummaryTable TABLE (
        COLUMN_A date,
        COLUMN_B nvarchar(16),
        COLUMN_C int
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @database nvarchar(64)
    DECLARE @log_database nvarchar(64)
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
    
    IF(LEFT(DB_NAME(), 4) = 'log_')
    BEGIN
        SET @log_database = DB_NAME()
        SET @database = SUBSTRING(DB_NAME(), 5, LEN(DB_NAME()) - 4)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @log_database = 'log_' + DB_NAME()
        SET @database = DB_NAME()
    END

    SET @sql = '
        SELECT c.COLUMN_A, C.COLUMN_B, pl.COLUMN_C
        FROM
            ' + @log_database + '..PICK_LOG pl
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ' + @database + '..[CUSTOM] c ON pl.CUSTOM_NUM = C.CUSTOM_NUM AND pl.COMPANY = c.COMPANY
        WHERE pl.[TIMESTAMP] > DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE())
    UNION
        SELECT c.COLUMN_A, C.COLUMN_B, pl.COLUMN_C
        FROM
            ' + @database + '..PICK_LOG pl
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ' + @database + '..[CUSTOM] c ON PL.CUSTOM_NUM = C.CUSTOM_NUM AND pl.COMPANY = c.COMPANY
        WHERE pl.[TIMESTAMP] > DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE())'

    INSERT INTO @PickSummaryTable ([DATE], CUSTOM_GROUP, CUSTOM_NUM, COMPANY, CUSTOM_DESC, LINES, QTY_SUF, DISTINCT_ORDERS)
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql 
    
    RETURN
END
GO
```

But this returns an error, so I can't create the function.

```
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.
```

Comment: as the error message stated. You can't do that inside a view. You can't also use dynamic SQL in a view

Comment: @Squirrel is there really no way around it?

Comment: If you need to use dynamic SQL inside a `VIEW`/`FUNCTION` this normally means you have a design flaw, and your focus should actually be fixing that.

Comment: @Larnu using a legacy system that requires views to present it to users. It is about to be replaced. Nothing that can be done to fix this right now.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Views, however, what you have above is problematic. To start, your Procedure is *wide* open to injection; that's a major security flaw. If you ever need to inject values into a statement **always** ensure that you properly quote it (normally with `QUOTENAME`, however use `REPLACE` for larger strings). Then you also use the `sp_` prefix in the Procedure's name, which is reversed for use by Microsoft for **S**pecial **P**rocedures. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Answer (score 0):

Neither views not functions can `exec` anything, so you can't use dynamic sql in a view (even if you try to hide the dynamic under various levels of nesting).

However, all is not lost! There are clever ways to do what you want.

One way would be to dynamically create synonyms, and then have a static view which uses those synonyms. For example:

```
create or alter procedure redirect_synonyms (@todb sysname) as begin
    drop synonym if exists sys_tables;
    declare @sql varchar(200) = concat('create synonym sys_tables for ', quotename(@todb), '.sys.tables')
    exec(@sql)
end

exec redirect_synonyms 'msdb';

create or alter view cleverview as select * from sys_tables;

select * from cleverview;
exec redirect_synonyms 'master';
select * from cleverview;
```

Comment: Careful, this is open to injection. You **need** to ensure you properly quote your dynamic object names with `QUOTENAME`.